# Apply Gradle's IDE plugin without adding it to build script

Tags: gradle

In short, I'd like to be able to generate IDEA/Eclipse project. But I don't like too much the necessity to add it to build script, because this info is unrelated to project structure. Would be nice to 'apply plugin' only once, for a single task. Something like

```
gradlew idea:idea
```

Thanks.

Comment: Idea can import gradle project without applying the plugin You mentioned. This is how I use it and it all works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't need project-specific configuration (which it sounds like you don't), you can add it to every project on your machine using an [init script](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html).

Add an init script that looks something like this.

`~/.gradle/init.d/idea.gradle`

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'idea'
}
```